# Bathroom Fan switch ground vs Neutral

Tags: hvac

I'm sure this has come up before.  I have been reading a lot about improper Neutrals or rather using ground as Neutral.

From what I can tell, the Neutral and Ground touch in the panel.  I thought the copper grounding rod in the flower bed was for fault protection.  But I've been told the path of least resistance is the Neutral and that the transformer is grounded on the street.

So what happens if you have low current running on the ground? You get shocked either way right? How are you not getting shocked?

So with all that in mind.  The modern bathroom Fan timer/moisture sensor switches take a neutral.  Most homes I assume just interrupt the hot wire and in goes a switch. If power comes in at the fan, a line is ran down to the switch and it's just interrupting the hot and then a ground wire. So no Neutral.

So how are people getting neutral if they don't tap the ground? New construction just plans for that and runs a neutral or what?

Comment: yes? they run a neutral. I *think* that **low** current on the ground for the purpose of switches is considered acceptable in some cases because it's easier than replacing the wires, but ideally there should be none.

Comment: Grounding rods have nothing to do with shock protection for people. Smallish amounts of current on the grounding system is quite common, because it is part of an alternative path back to the transformer supplying the premises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code (NEC) was changed in 2011 so all *new* switch boxes must have a neutral wire to them, so smart switches can be used. Many jurisdictions are regularly several years behind the latest NEC. Right now, about half the states are on 2020 (many with variations) and most of the rest 2014 or 2017, but Indiana still using 2008.

Switches before could be on switch loops and not have neutral. This causes problems when people want smart switches/timers/sensors that need neutral.

They either need to rewire, do a hack with ground (usually bad), or carefully choose a smart switch which does not need neutral. There are some smart switches designed to legitimately use ground instead of neutral. Some of these are actually designed to use neutral if available but can use ground if neutral is not available. You can only use ground instead of neutral if a UL or ETL (or similar) listed device includes instructions allowing it. If it isn't in the instructions, or if the device is not properly listed, then you are violating the NEC, and by extension your local regulations, by doing so.

Using ground instead of neutral isn't a problem at very low current levels, which is why it is allowed in certain cases. But it can be a big problem, which is why you can't just decide on your own "neutral missing, I'll use ground instead".

Some switches have the power going to the switch first, instead of a light and this provides neutral in the switch box, neutral is just connected to neutral going to the light. But you do need to make sure that if you have multiple neutral wires (e.g., one to a receptacle and a different one to a light) that you tap into the correct one. Hot/neutral currents must always be equal.

Comment: I was going to write my own answer, but yours was close enough so I edited it. If you don't like my edits, feel free to revert (except I'd really like to keep in the actual NEC versions, as that is quite relevant).

Answer (score 1):

Neutral is a separate system altogether. It comes from the utility transformer, to your panel, to your outlets.  It is the normal path of power.

Ground comes from the ground rod, to your panel, to your outlets.

> From what I can tell, the Neutral and Ground touch in the panel.

That is the neutral-ground equipotential bond.  It serves a number of useful purposes.

- It avoids a situation where the neutral coming from the transformer is 400 volts *above* the local ground, just because of random failures and/or voltage gradient across the ground.   That can happen; ask a British electrician.  (well, it can happen *there* because they don't do ground rods).
- Human-generated elecricity does not want to get back to ground.  It wants to get back to source.  Source is neutral.  If an appliance has a dead short from 120V to ground, the N-G bond assures the massive fault current can get back to neutral - and flow enough current to trip the breaker. We want the breaker to trip in that situation.
- Natural electricity (static electricity, and lightning) does want to get back to ground. This assures that if it gets on hot or neutral somehow, it can quickly get back to ground.

> So what happens if you have low current running on the ground? You get shocked either way right? How are you not getting shocked?

Depends how low. Some very low currents are too low to do harm.

> So with all that in mind. The modern bathroom Fan timer/moisture sensor switches take a neutral. Most homes I assume just interrupt the hot wire and in goes a switch. If power comes in at the fan, a line is ran down to the switch and it's just interrupting the hot and then a ground wire. So no Neutral.

*SOME* switches take a neutral.  Not all.  There are 4 ways to avoid neutral use:

- Have the human provide the power (i.e. those spring-wound timer switches that you don't think are cool anymore).
- Design the switch to be able to leak current through the light (i.e. the way most older dimmers work).
- Have the thing that needs neutral be located elsewhere. (e.g. careful choice of smart switch location on a 3-way switch system).
- Leak a highly controlled **and very tiny** amount of current onto the ground wire -- there is a certifiable standard for making that safe, and **UL will approve switches which do it properly**.   Note this does not provide enough energy to transmit on WiFi without use of a battery.

The existence of these UL-approved "no neutral" switches has tempted some people to say "Well I'm smarter than all the engineers at UL.  If they can approve it for carefully designed switches, I can do it for ANY switch!"  No.

> So how are people getting neutral if they don't tap the ground? New construction just plans for that and runs a neutral or what?

What do you mean "if they don't"?  They're either a) choosing products that don't need neutral by design, b) choosing UL approved products able to use ground, c) putting the powered feature elsewhere, or d) managing to live their lives without it.